# FFMPEG Unable to find a suitable output format for 'pipe:' pipe:: Invalid argument

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, pipe, drone.io

I want to stream video from my drone real time to a WEBUI using ffmpeg. But i get the follwong errors.
The code works but i don't think ishould have gotten this error.
Can somebody help with this issue? This is my drone commands along with the streaming video codes. I have only added the code to get data.
Below is the error:
[pipe error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oV2HV.png)

My code is as follows :

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

DEFAULT_DISTANCE = 0.30
DEFAULT_SPEED = 10
DEFAULT_DEGREE = 10

FRAME_X = int(960/3)
FRAME_Y = int(720/3)
FRAME_AREA = FRAME_X * FRAME_Y

FRAME_SIZE = FRAME_AREA * 3
FRAME_CENTER_X = FRAME_X / 2
FRAME_CENTER_Y = FRAME_Y / 2

CMD_FFMPEG = (f'ffmpeg - hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device opencl -i pipe:0 '
              f'-pix_fmt bgr24 -s {FRAME_X}x{FRAME_Y}  -f rawvideo pipe:1')


class DroneManager(metaclass=Singleton):
    def __init__(self, host_ip='192.168.10.2', host_port=8890,
                 drone_ip='192.168.10.1', drone_port=8889,
                 is_imperial=False, speed=DEFAULT_SPEED):
        self.host_ip = host_ip
        self.host_port = host_port
        self.drone_ip = drone_ip
        self.drone_port = drone_port
        self.drone_address = (drone_ip, drone_port)
        self.is_imperial = is_imperial
        self.speed = speed
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.host_ip, self.host_port))

        self.response = None
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self._response_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.receive_response,
                                                 args=(self.stop_event,))
        self._response_thread.start()

        self.patrol_event = None
        self.is_patrol = False
        self._patrol_semaphore = threading.Semaphore(1)
        self._thread_patrol = None

        self.proc = subprocess.Popen(CMD_FFMPEG.split(' '),
                                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.proc_stdin = self.proc.stdin
        self.proc_stdout = self.proc.stdout

        self.video_port = 11111

        self._receive_video_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=self.receive_video,
            args=(self.stop_event, self.proc_stdin,
                  self.host_ip, self.video_port,))
        self._receive_video_thread.start()

        self.send_command('command')
        self.send_command('streamon')
        self.set_speed(self.speed)

    def receive_response(self, stop_event):
        while not stop_event.is_set():
            try:
                self.response, ip = self.socket.recvfrom(3000)
                logger.info({'action': 'receive_response',
                             'response': self.response})
            except socket.error as ex:
                logger.error({'action': 'receive_response',
                              'ex': ex})
                break

    def __dell__(self):
        self.stop()

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()
        retry = 0
        while self._response_thread.is_alive():
            time.sleep(0.3)
            if retry > 30:
                break
            retry += 1
        self.socket.close()
        os.kill(self.proc.pid, signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)

    def send_command(self, command):
        logger.info({'action': 'send_command', 'command': command})
        self.socket.sendto(command.encode('utf-8'), self.drone_address)

        retry = 0
        while self.response is None:
            time.sleep(0.3)
            if retry > 3:
                break
            retry += 1

        if self.response is None:
            response = None
        else:
            response = self.response.decode('utf-8')
        self.response = None
        return response

    def takeoff(self):
        return self.send_command('takeoff')

    def land(self):
        return self.send_command('land')

    def move(self, direction, distance):
        distance = float(distance)
        if self.is_imperial:
            distance = int(round(distance * 30.48))
        else:
            distance = int(round(distance * 100))
        return self.send_command(f'{direction} {distance}')

    def up(self, distance=DEFAULT_DISTANCE):
        return self.move('up', distance)

    def down(self, distance=DEFAULT_DISTANCE):
        return self.move('down', distance)

    def left(self, distance=DEFAULT_DISTANCE):
        return self.move('left', distance)

    def right(self, distance=DEFAULT_DISTANCE):
        return self.move('right', distance)

    def forward(self, distance=DEFAULT_DISTANCE):
        return self.move('forward', distance)

    def back(self, distance=DEFAULT_DISTANCE):
        return self.move('back', distance)

    def set_speed(self, speed):
        return self.send_command(f'speed {speed}')

    def clockwise(self, degree=DEFAULT_DEGREE):
        return self.send_command(f'cw {degree}')

    def counter_clockwise(self, degree=DEFAULT_DEGREE):
        return self.send_command(f'ccw {degree}')

    def flip_front(self):
        return self.send_command('flip f')

    def flip_back(self):
        return self.send_command('flip b')

    def flip_left(self):
        return self.send_command('flip l')

    def flip_right(self):
        return self.send_command('flip r')

    def patrol(self):
        if not self.is_patrol:
            self.patrol_event = threading.Event()
            self._thread_patrol = threading.Thread(
                target=self._patrol,
                args=(self._patrol_semaphore, self.patrol_event,))
            self._thread_patrol.start()
            self.is_patrol = True

    def stop_patrol(self):
        if self.is_patrol:
            self.patrol_event.set()
            retry = 0
            while self._thread_patrol.is_alive():
                time.sleep(0.3)
                if retry > 300:
                    break
                retry += 1
            self.is_patrol = False

    def _patrol(self, semaphore, stop_event):
        is_acquire = semaphore.acquire(blocking=False)
        if is_acquire:
            logger.info({'action': '_patrol', 'status': 'acquire'})
            with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
                stack.callback(semaphore.release)
                status = 0
                while not stop_event.is_set():
                    status += 1
                    if status == 1:
                        self.up()
                    if status == 2:
                        self.clockwise(180)
                    if status == 3:
                        self.down()
                    if status == 4:
                        status = 0
                    time.sleep(5)
        else:
            logger.warning({'action': '_patrol', 'status': 'not_acquire'})

    def receive_video(self, stop_event, pipe_in, host_ip, video_port):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as sock_video:
            sock_video.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
            sock_video.settimeout(5)
            sock_video.bind((host_ip, video_port))
            data = bytearray(2048)
            while not self.stop_event.is_set():
                try:
                    size, addr = sock_video.recvfrom_into(data)
                    logger.info({'action': 'receive_video', 'data': data})
                except socket.timeout as ex:
                    logger.warning({'action': 'receive_video', 'ex': ex})
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    continue
                except socket.error as ex:
                    logger.error({'action': 'receive_video', 'ex': ex})
                    break

                try:
                    pipe_in.write(data[:size])
                    pipe_in.flush()
                except Exception as ex:
                    logger.info({'action': 'receive_video', 'ex': ex})
                    break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `- hwaccel auto` to `-hwaccel auto`.

Comment: @ashiyaanunhuck What is the actual ffmpeg command being executed?

Comment: @ashiyaanunhuck The ffmpeg command in the code is obvious in your question. ffmpeg is not literally being executed as `(f'ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device opencl -i pipe:0 ' f'-pix_fmt bgr24 -s {FRAME_X}x{FRAME_Y} -f rawvideo pipe:1')`. What I am looking for is an example of the ffmpeg command that actually gets executed. There is likely a problem with quoting or escaping, and showing the actual command as executed will make it easier to see the problem.

Comment: Thank you I have resolved it. There are too many spaces in CMD_FFMPEG. I have another issue concerning ffmpeg. I posted it. Could you please try and help me?I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @ashiyaanunhuck Sorry, but I don't have an answer for your new question.